# XML Schema to count concatenated innertext character count

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm developing schema(*.xsd).

```
<kwd-group kwd-group-type="keywords">
<kwd>body-image concerns</kwd>
<kwd>body change strategies</kwd>
<kwd>body dissatisfaction</kwd>
<kwd>body mass index (BMI)</kwd>
<kwd>eating attitudes</kwd>
<kwd>eating behaviors</kwd>
<kwd>eating disorder</kwd>
<kwd>preadolescent boys</kwd>
<kwd>sociocultural influences</kwd>
</kwd-group>
```

I need to restrict the element "kwd" **innertext**. The concatenation of all the kwd's innertext not greater than 1000 characters.

Please guide me..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict the length of the `kwd` element, as well as the maximum number of occurences:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Max50String">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="50" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

<xsd:element name="kwd" type="Max50String" maxOccurs="20"/>
```

Comment: No, i need to restrict only total kwd innertext concatenated length not greater than 1000. May be a single kwd element contain 1000 characters or sum of kwd elements innertext characters are 1000.

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved in an xsd context. Maybe you should add a post-validation step on your code, verifying the requirement.